# Javascript Shorthand to Check if val Equals One of Two

Tags: javascript

I feel like I come across this a lot and that intuitively, there should be a way to do something like this:

```
if (userType ==="admin" || userType === "superUser"){
 // do stuff
}
```

In a more elegant way, like this:

```
if (userType === ("admin" || "superUser")){
 // do stuff
}
```

Obviously that^ doesn't work because if the first value resolves to true, it will never check if it's the second ("superuser").

Is there shorthand to do this in a JS if-statement where you wouldn't have to repeat the variable name?

Switch statements don't count! ;D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't provide out of the box such a syntax.

Now, you can do something of close enough with the [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method.
It returns `true` if the element is found in the array.
Otherwise if returns `false`.

```
var userTypes = ["admin", "superUser"];
if (userTypes.includes(userType)){
  // do stuff
}
```

or by inlining the array value :

```
if (["admin", "superUser"].includes(userType)){
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: The inlining method is probably the closest to what I wanted.  Thanks David!

Comment: you are very welcome. I think too :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use an `array` with `indexOf`. something like

```
if(["superUser", "admin"].indexOf(userType) >= 0){
    //code goes here
}
```

Comment: I'm curious if there's an advantage to using '>= 0' rather than the more obvious '!== -1'? It's more obvious, imo, because -1 is what indexOf() returns when the item isn't in the array, which is what we're interested in.
Of course, includes() is better than both.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object for fast checking.

```
if ({ admin: 1, superUser: 1 }[userType]) {
    // do something if true
}
```

Comment: Why does this not throw a syntax error? Using `{ admin: 1, superUser: 1}[userType]` on it's own throws one. --- Ah. It's the brackets... never mind.